# Liferay Documents and Media ( Media Gallery hook) sort latest uploaded folder first

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I want the folders in Documents and Media Portlet to be sorted by last one uploaded. So that the last folder I uploaded is displayed first. Any idea how to do this ? In which jsp file ?

P.S In Admin/Content/Documents and Media there is a option Sort By. But it affects only the back office, not the front-end. In the front-end the folders which are last uploaded are displayed on the last page not on the first.

Comment: the portlet is the Document and Media display or Document and Media?

Comment: Which Liferay version?

Comment: The portlet is Document and Media. Liferay version is 6.2 GA2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify any jsp to get this behaviour. You should go to Admin/Content/Documents and Media and enter in configuration of the Documents and Media portlet. You will see the avaliable columns, so you have to select the modification date. After this you can order the documents by modification in the front view.

Comment: I selected the modified date. Can you explain me how can I order them in the front view baceuse there is not any dropdown in the front?